# handbrake-js (node) no video on html5-Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video, handbrake, handbrake-js

I'm trying to convert a video using handbrake-js for node.
At first I tried specifying the bitrate, video size, codecs, etc. The goal is to generate several html5 compatible streams to be used as a source on a canvas video for webGL. Everything seems to work fine, it outputs the video, and when I open it using Quicktime or VLC it looks fine, however, when I use it on a  tag, there is no video, just audio.

The following code is called whithin a function which receives an "ops" JSON, with the width and height.

```
hb.spawn({ input: new_location + "original" + ext, output: new_location + ops.name, optimize: true, vb: ops.vb, "width": ops.width, "height": ops.height, "rate": 30 })
```

The console shows the video being converted, and a clean exit.
but webGL reports:

> [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-0x7fbf21074c00]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.

Note: The video *IS* a power of 2 (1024x512). Also when I play the original file it doesen't show the error.

To debug, I have even attached the video to the HTML, and changed the CSS to show it. but there is no video. just audio.

I have even tried:

```
hb.spawn({ input: "input.mp4", output: "output.m4v" })
```

and a simple 
Well... input.mp4 displays fine. output.m4v always fails to show video on HTML (Chrome, safari seems to work just fine).

Any ideas?

Comment: hb.spawn({ input: new_location + "original" + ext, output: new_location + ops.name, preset: "Normal" }) 

Seems to work. but I'd like more control, and other encoding options as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say `preset: Normal` works, then you can run `handbrake --preset-list` (using handbrake-js [installed as a command-line app](https://github.com/75lb/handbrake-js#as-a-command-line-app)) to see which encoder options the "normal" preset uses:

```
+ Normal:  -e x264  -q 20.0 -a 1 -E ffaac -B 160 -6 dpl2 -R Auto -D 0.0 --audio-copy-mask aac,ac3,dtshd,dts,mp3 --audio-fallback ffac3 -f mp4 --loose-anamorphic --modulus 2 -m --x264-preset veryfast --h264-profile main --h264-level 4.0
```

So, try running `hb.spawn` using the options above and remove any options you don't need.